# Stripping whitespace and dot from hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove whitespace and dot from hyperlinks all rules are working fine except its not removing dot from url. Here are few examples

```
 <a href="   http://www.example.com   ">example site</a>
 <a href="   http://www.example.com">example 2</a>
 <a href="http://www.example.com.">final example</a>


  $text = preg_replace('/<a href="([\s]+)?([^ "\']*)([\s]+)?(\.)?">([^<]*)<\/a>/', '<a href="\\2">\\5</a>', $text);
```

In the last example RE should remove dot from url. Dot is optional so I wrote this rule (.)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your dot is already matched by `([^ "\']*)` group.

Change it to `([^ "\']*?)` - ungreedy version.

And also I suggest you to replace `([\s]+)?(\.)?` with `[\s.]*` to handle "www.example.com.    " strings.

Answer (score 1):

How about `<a href="([\s]+)?([^ "\']*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5})([\s]+)?(\.)?">([^<]*)<\/a>`? `.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}`?

It will catch .com, .info, .edu and even something like .com.au

Comment: Thanks it works perfect for urls like http://xyz.com but it will not work for http://xyz.com/another-page I am trying to fix your RE

Answer (score 1):

This will trim up the hrefs (I asume you mean to trim them).

for both `'"` value delimeters (expanded):

```
(<a \s+ href \s* = \s*)
(?|
     (") \s* ([^"]*?) [\.\s]* (")
  |  (') \s* ([^']*?) [\.\s]* (')
)
([^>]*>)
```

replacement is: `$1$2$3$4$5`

or,

for just `"` value delimeter (expanded):

```
(<a \s+ href \s* = \s* ")
\s* 
([^"]*?)
[\.\s]*
(" [^>]*>)
```

replacement is: `$1$2$3`

Answer (score 0):

The following is un-tested.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->Load('source.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// We starts from the root element
$query = 'a';

$anchors = $xpath->query('a');

foreach($anchors as $aElement) {
    $aElement->setAttribute('href', trim($aElement->getAttribute('href'), ' .'));
}

$doc->saveHTMLFile('new-source.html');
```